# Why does the set $\{1,3,5,7... ; 2,4,6,8...\}$ qualify as well-ordered? How to explain this notation?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, order-theory

The set  {odd natural numbers greater than 0  }U {even natural numbers}

that is, the set

> $\bigcup \{ \{1,3,5,7...\}, \{2,4,6,8...\}  \}$

**also strangely written**

> $\{1,3,5,7... ; 2,4,6,8...\}$ .

is often given as an example of a well-ordered set ( a set such that for all subset there is a first element).

I have some problems with this example.

(1) First, which relation orders this set? Could this relation be defined *explicitly*? Is this relation somewhat analogous to lexigraphic order? So I don't understand how this set can be an *ordered* set.

(2) Second, I don't understand how it is *well*-ordered. In order to be well ordered, every subset should have a first element. But apparently, the set  $\{7,2\}$ is a subset of my set. What is the first element of $\{7,2\}$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sets have no "inherent order". They can have a *natural order* (such as $\Bbb N$ or $\Bbb R$ having a natural ordering that we consider somehow "part of the set"), but they do not have an inherent ordering.

Writing $\{1,3,5,\dots;0,2,4,\dots\}$ is a terrible abuse of notation.

But it is indeed a well-ordering of $\Bbb N$ which is *not* its natural ordering (which is also a well-ordering). Here is an explicit definition:

$$m\prec n\iff \begin{cases}m\text{ is odd and }n\text{ is even}, &\text{ or}\\m\equiv n\pmod 2\text{ and }m<n.\end{cases}$$

To see it is a well-ordering, note that each of the subsets, evens and odds, is ordered in the natural way which makes *that* part a well-order, and so given a non-empty set, it either has a smallest odd number or it is a subset of the even numbers.

Comment: @AsafKalaglia. Thanks a lot!  So in the context of my question, putting first odd numbers and second even ones, the first element of { 7,2} is 7, am I right?

Comment: Yes. I misremembered between reading the question and writing my answer (mainly because whenever I gave that example, I would put the even numbers first. I'll edit to fix this.)

Comment: @AsafKalaglia. The set ( with its abusive notation) is given in my book as the union of {odds} and  {even} to show, as example,  that the union of a family of WOS is also a WOS. Does it really qualify as such a union? As noted JoséCarlosSantos in a previous answer, normally the union of these two sets is simply N with its natural ordering.

Comment: I don't know who wrote the book. There is a notion of summation of orders, and the sum of well-orders over a well-ordered index, is again a well-order. My guess is that this was their meaning.

Comment: @AsafKalaglia.The reference is Schaum's Outline of Set Theory.

Answer (score 5):

As suggested, a well-ordered set is one in which each subset has a first element. The natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ with their usual relation $\le$ form a prototypical example:

$$0 < 1 < 2 < 3 < 4 < 5 < \cdots$$

however what I believe your example, written as

$$\{ 1, 3, 5, 7, \cdots ; 2, 4, 6, 8, \cdots \}$$

is *supposed* to indicate (what book or other reference is this from?) is a well-ordered set in which the order looks like this:

$$1 < 3 < 5 < 7 < \cdots < 2 < 4 < 6 < 8 < \cdots$$

in other words, it's all the *odd* numbers ordered in the usual way, and then *after ALL of them*, all the even numbers, again, ordered in the usual way. The trick is that *every odd number is "less" than every even number* in this new ordering, and thus shows a well-order which is *different from* the usual ordering of the natural numbers. It's meant to show that there are more forms a well-order can take than one might at first expect. In particular, it is a well-order which has an "internal infinity" in that there are an *infinite* number of elements between any odd number and any even number.

With regard to the question of the initial element of the subset $\{7, 2\}$, the answer is simple: looking at the sequence as shown above and where 7 and 2 fall therein, it is seen at a glance to be **7** (not 2). In terms of the mathematical definition, since 7 is odd, and 2 is even, 2 must be "greater" than every odd number, hence also greater than 7 and 7 is the initial element.