# Why is " omega" = ord (N) a " limit element".

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ordinals

I'm trying to understand ordinal numbers in Lipschutz, Set Theory.

The author has correctly explained what is a limit element.

A previous example given is that , in the set

{ 1,3,5.... ;  2,4,6,8...}

2 is a limit element ( having no immediate predecessor, without being the first element).

The second example given is "omega" = the ordinal of the set of counting numbers.

My question : what makes of "omega" a limit element in the class of ordinal numbers?

---

**ADD** (*The Sympathizer*, UE+1556.957 Ms): The "prior example" referenced with set-like notation was that mentioned in this post:

[Why does the set $\{1,3,5,7... ; 2,4,6,8...\}$ qualify as well-ordered? How to explain this notation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3208098/why-does-the-set-1-3-5-7-2-4-6-8-qualify-as-well-ordered-how-to-e)

This notation is from an unnamed third party source and is meant to represent the set of positive natural numbers well-ordered with the odd numbers first, followed by the even numbers:

$$1 < 3 < 5 < 7 < \cdots < 2 < 4 < 6 < 8 < \cdots$$

with ordinality $2\omega$.

Comment: A limit ordinal is an ordinal that isn't 0 and isn't a successor ordinal. Clearly, $\omega$ is neither.

Comment: A nit to pick.  It's not correct to talk about the "set" of ordinal numbers.  In the usual version of set theory, the ordinal numbers are a proper class (a collection that, in a meaningful way, is "too big" to be a set).

Comment: *Why* are you using Schaum's book?

Comment: And why are you *still* using that awful notation, despite being told it's confusing, misleading, abusive (to the notation), and borderline incorrect in any standard context?

Comment: And why, if the author has "correctly explained what is a limit element" you have difficulty assessing why $\omega$ is a limit ordinal? If you can say the explanation is correct, then you should be able to answer your own question.

Comment: @Asaf Guess which book was my first exposure to set theory. I have a fondness for some of those books.

Comment: @Andrés: Guess which whisky was my first exposure to whisky. I have no fondness for some of those scotches I had when I was much younger. I'm not saying that Schaum's are all bad, or that this one is bad. I'm just wondering why Schaum, especially since it's not something you hear about when you talk to actual set theorists (as opposed to Enderton or Just & Weese or Jech & Hrbacek).

Comment: @AsafKaragila. I understand perfectly that for set theory specialists some basic books have absolutely no value. I just want to say that I'm a beginner in mathematics ( being trained in philosophy and needing mathematics to understand logic, philosophy of langiage, some ethics and philosophy of science). I tried many books before giving up , unable to cope with difficulties ( Halmos, Enderton, Stoll). Also sorry for using  again the abusive notation in question. I did this to clarify the context and to clarify my question, since this notation was used in the example I did not understand.

Comment: @Ray LittleRock : I understand Youzzle :) #mehhr - may I add or suggest some remarks to the end of your question post regarding the notation for other readers' benefit to clarify what it means and why it's used here?

Comment: @The_Sympathizer. Of course you can.

Comment: @Ray LittleRock : Added. Thanks.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer. By the way what do "Youzzle" and " #mehhr" mean ? ( not a native english speaker, sorry).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because, topologically, $\omega$ is the limit point of the preceding ordinals, i.e. the natural numbers.

A "limit point" of a set is a point which can be "approximated as close as we like" by elements of that set. This, of course, requires us to have a notion of "approximation", which is what topology does, and orders, like those on the ordinals, can be considered as a source of such because you can consider the approximation of a point by an *interval*: if you have a point $p$, and you can bracket it in $(a, b)$, i.e. $a < p < b$, then you can say $(a, b)$ is like a "confidence interval", as in taking measurements: e.g. if I say I'm around 169-171 cm tall, that's an approximation with a 2 cm interval. If you now make $a$ and $b$ "closer", i.e. have an interval $(a', b')$ such that $a < a'$ and $b' < b$, and yet $p$ is still contained therein, then the second interval approximates better.

Likewise, if we have a subset, $S$ of some ordered set, here (a suitable initial segment of (**)) the ordinals, we can say that that subset has as *limit point* $l$ - which need not be in it, but must be in the larger ordered set - if in *every*, *open* interval $(a, b)$ which contains $l$, there is also a point from $S$. That point is an "approximation", and the intuition is that the smaller the interval, the closer that approximation is thereto, and you can always find an approximation from $S$ no matter how small you make the interval.

In that regard, $\omega$ has this property with respect to $\mathbb{N}$ because if we have any open interval $(a, b)$ of ordinals containing $\omega$, then we must of course $a < \omega < b$, but that first inequality means $a$ must be a natural since there is nothing before $\omega$ but naturals. Hence there is a natural one larger (its successor) and such "approximates" $\omega$(*) and, moreover, we can, by making $a$ larger, get better approximations thereof. Thus $\omega$ is a limit point and hence this is why the name "limit ordinal". Similar considerations apply to all other limit ordinals.

---

(*) The notion of something being "approximately infinite", despite not making *strict* sense, is very, very useful, but can also be a poison pill if you're not careful: if something is really huge, but finite, compared to something else that is at a much smaller scale we happen to be interested in, it so often happens that taking the "really huge" thing as *actually* infinite often makes things a lot easier. One example is from physics, where you can, say, model a capacitor made from two parallel metal sheets very accurately, provided they aren't too far apart, as being made from infinite sheets. A *misuse* of this notion is in treating the Earth as infinite when you have 7.5 billion people covering it all demanding more and more profligate use of natural resources :) There you're in territory where the approximation breaks down as the scales are now comparable.

(**) The ordinals are too numerous to be collected into a set without creating a logical contradiction, at least in typical conceptions of set theory.